# 8 ≡ 6 (mod 2)? Is the (mod 2) applied to both sides?

Tags: discrete-mathematics

8 ≡ 6 (mod 2)

Is this True or False? And why?

Is the (mod 2) applied to both sides of the logical equivalence?

Comment: ${}\pmod2$ is not an operator. It makes no sense to say it is "applied to both sides". Moreover here $\equiv$ denotes congruence, not logical equivalence. $a\equiv b\pmod n$ means that $a-b$ is a multiple of $n$. You may verify that $8-6$ is a multiple of $2$.

Comment: Logical equivalence is not the only kind of equivalence - the notion also belongs, for example, to the world of equivalence relations. Congruence modulo a positive integer is easily shown to be an equivalence relation.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown: mod is sometimes an operator, for example in "Let $x=y \mod 2$". This is precisely the source of OP's problem.

Comment: @TonyK But it is never an operator when written like this.

Comment: Statements such as "Let $x=y\mod2$" are abominations. @TonyK

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown: That's as may be. I am not making a value judgment here, I'm just pointing out that it's a genuine source of confusion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In mathematics, "(mod 2)" is usually not a function. It does not "apply" to a side of an equation. It is a description of the *entire* equation: that the equation should be taken "(mod 2)".

Depending on the vocabulary you are comfortable with, this means one of the following (equivalent) things:

- The equation holds "up to multiples of 2".
- There is a $k$ in the integers, so that adding $2k$ to one side of the equation makes it true.
- If you subtract one side of the equation from the other, the result is divisible by 2.
- The equation should be read as being about elements of $\mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z$.

For example, the following are all true:
$$
8 = 0 \pmod2\\
15 = -9 \pmod 2\\
0 = 18 \pmod2\\
20 = 20 \pmod2
$$
To emphasize that these are (usually) not exactly equalities of integers, sometimes additionally the equals symbol $=$ is replaced by another, usually $\equiv$.

Comment: You mean $8\equiv0\pmod2$ (passim).